# Random Variable with bounded first moment and unbounded higher moments

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am wondering whether one can find a random variable, with density $f$ supported on an unbounded interval, such that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x| f(x) dx < \infty $$
but
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x|^p f(x) dx = \infty \quad \forall p>1$$
Of course if I choose a certain $\bar{p}$, I can build a Pareto distribution with parameters such that the above hold, but what I would need is to have a density *independent* of $p$, such that the above hold $\forall p$.

Do you have any hints?
Thanks!

Comment: How about the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Smaller_moments) ?

Comment: But then also the integral with p=1 would fail to converge

Comment: What do you mean a "density independent of $p$"? Once you fix $\bar{p} = 1$ in the Pareto family, $f$ is independent of $p$.

Comment: If I fix $\bar{p}=1$ in the Pareto family, I cannot have bounded integral neither for $p=1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Fubini's theorem, it's not hard to derive for any $p>0$,
$$\mathbb{E}[|X|^{p}]=\int_{0}^{\infty}px^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(|X|>x)dx.$$
Which means $\mathbb{E}[|X|^{p}]<\infty$ only if the tail probability $\mathbb{P}(|X|>x)$ decays faster than $\frac{1}{x^{p}}$. So what you are looking for is a distribution with tail probability decays faster than $\frac{1}{x}$, but slower than $\frac{1}{x^{p}}$ for any $p>1$. A simple choice is letting
$$\mathbb{P}(|X|>x)\asymp\frac{1}{x(\log x)^{t}}, \quad\text{for some }t>1.$$
For instance assume $X$ has support $[e,\infty)$, by some normalization,  let
$$f(x)=\biggl(\frac{2e}{x^{2}(\log x)^{3}}+\frac{e}{x^{2}(\log x)^{2}}\biggr)1_{[e,\infty)}(x).$$
This gives
$$\mathbb{P}(X>x)=\frac{e}{x(\log x)^{2}}\quad\text{and}\quad\mathbb{E}[X]=2e.$$

Comment: Thank you, but with the proposed $f$ the integral with $p=1$ does not seem to converge (I have double checked on WolframAlpha, too)...

Comment: @gm3 My bad, I fixed this.